# Typescript. Can I distinguish between compile-time and run-time dependence

Tags: typescript

I'm using the CommonJS module conventions, since I'm targeting node.js for testing and using browserify to make a single .js file.  Currently my modules are circularly dependent. What I'd like to do is to indicate that module `value` depends on module `pnode`, but only at compile-time. I.e. any run-time dependence should be flagged as an error.  E.g. if module `pnode` declares a type T, then in module `value`, I'd like for a declaration like `var a : pnode.T` to compile without error, but an expression like `new pnode.T()` or `a instanceof pnode.T` would be in error because they creates a run-time dependence.

Is there a way to do this?

Motivation: Currently `pnode` and `value` are circularly dependent. That's ok as long as there is no circular dependence at run time. Circular dependence at run time causes a problem because node.js does not handle it correctly or even warn about it.  My current code looks like this

File `pnode.ts`

```
import value = require('./value') ;

module pnode {

    export abstract class Label {
    }
    export class LambdaLabel {
        step() {
            return new value.ClosureV(this) ;
        }
    }
}

export = pnode ;
```

File `value.ts`

```
import pnode = require('./pnode') ; // Would like to avoid this.

module value {

    export class ClosureV {

        constructor( func : pnode.Label ) {

            if ( func instanceof pnode.Label ) // Would like an error here.
                console.log("a") ; else console.log("b") ;
        }
    }
}

export = value;
```

What I've tried.  I was hoping that replacing the line

```
 import pnode = require('./pnode') ; // Would like to avoid this.
```

with

```
/// <reference path="pnode.ts" />
```

might do the trick, but it did not.  There are various ways that I have considered eliminating the compile-time circular dependence, so that is my fall-back option.

Comment: You can make the compiler output `.d.ts` files for your modules and then reference the `pnode.d.ts` from `value.ts`. That way you're telling the compiler that "these definitions are ok and will be present at runtime". Another option is to move all shared types from these files to a 3rd one, let's say `shared`, then both of these modules will reference `shared` and you're avoiding circular dependency.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thanks. This sounds promising. I generated pnode.d.ts, deleted `import pnode = require('./pnode') ;`, and added `/// <reference path="pnode.d.ts" />` in its place. But now I get an error where `pnode.Label` is used. The error is `Cannot find namespace 'pnode'`

Answer (score 0):

If you compile `pnode.ts` with the declaration flag you'll get this `.d.ts` file:

```
declare module pnode {
    abstract class Label {
    }
    class LambdaLabel {
        step(): any;
    }
}
export = pnode;
```

Then when you reference it:

```
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />

module value {
    export class ClosureV {
        constructor( func : pnode.Label ) {}
    }
}
```

You'll get the error you described: `Cannot find namespace 'pnode'`.
That's because the compiler knows that this `.d.ts` file represents a CommonJS module because it ends with `export = pnode;`.

If you remove that line (or comment it out) then the error goes away.  You'll need to remove this line after every compilation (or have a script that does it for you) but it will work.

In any case I believe that having a third module which acts as a share module for the others will give you more flexibility, as you'll also be able to have common classes/functions that are available at runtime.
Not to mention that you won't need to take another action after compilation.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work.  I rewrote `value.ts` as in this answer except with `pnode.d.ts` instead of `temp.d.ts` and keeping the offending run-time dependency.  Then I compiled pnode with `tsc --module commonjs --moduleResolution node --declaration pnode.ts ` to make the .d.ts file.  Next I deleted the `export =` line from pnode.d.ts.  Finally compiled `tsc --module commonjs --moduleResolution node value.ts`. But this gave the `Cannot find namespace 'pnode'.` on the declaration of parameter `func`.

Comment: I have no idea why that's not working for you. Which version of tsc are you using? I have `1.8.10` and it works. There's one other thing I had to do to make it work, I wasn't able to compile `pnode.ts` when my `value.ts` had a reference to `pnode`, it errored with: `cannot write file value.d.ts because it would overwrite input file`. So I had to change to the `require(pnode)`, compile `pnode`, change `value.ts` to reference the `pnode.d.ts` and then (after removing the export line) it worked.